# OBJECTIVE-C Stack with array of int

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to create a stack with array of int (2 dimensional : int[9][9]), but I can't.
I tried the NSMutableArray which needs objects. So I tried to use NSValue to transform my array to a NSObject, but I keep having lot ouf trouble.

Can you please give me some help ?

I push an array (a grid) in the (void)saveGrid function.
I need to recover the last grid in the (IBAction)undo function.

Here is my last-try code source : (where Im transforming my 2D-array (9*9) to a 1D-array (81))

```
- (void)saveGrid {
 int longGrid[81];
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
   longGrid[(i+1)*(j+1)-1] = matrix[i][j];
  }
 }
 NSValue *valObj;
 valObj = [NSValue value:&longGrid withObjCType:@encode(int **)];
 [TGrid addObject:valObj];
}

- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender {
 [TGrid removeLastObject];
 int *valPtr;
 [[TGrid lastObject] getValue:&valPtr];
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = valPtr[(i+1)*(j+1)-1];
  }
 }
}
```

*(TGrid is NSMutableArray typed.)*

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your thinking. You want to use an NSArray, correct? Or NSMutableArray? Either way, you can't store ints in these. You can only store objects, so an integer would be an NSNumber object. It's actually a subclass of NSValue, so you don't need to use NSValue.

So with that it's pretty easy to create an NSMutableArray, populate it with the numbers, which are of the NSNumber object, and then create another NSMutableArray and populate that one with a bunch of NSMutableArrays. There you have it, a 2 dimensional array.

Secondly, It's not a good idea to subclass NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, and the mutable versions of that.  In Cocoa, many classes are actually implemented as class clusters, which are a bunch of implementation-specific classes hidden behind a common interface. When you make an NSString object, you might actually end up getting an NSLiteralString, NSCFString, NSSimpleCString, NSBallOfString, or any number of undocumented implementation-detail objects.

Comment: Subclassing the collection class clusters is actually very easy to do; you just need to implement the core methods.   The rest of the methods on the abstract classes are entirely implemented in terms of the core methods.   I don't necessarily think that subclassing NS*Array is sensible in this case, though.

Comment: @bbum, I hear what you're saying. I'm just saying that in his case, it's not a good idea to do so. He wouldn't know all the core methods, etc. Better to stay away from that at this point.

Comment: I need a mutable array. NSNumber is not sufficient, I need NSValue if I want to store an array (I looked up in the developer help, they used NSValue to store a char array, so I thought it would be working for int).

Your method must work, I will try this solution (I only need a NSArray of NSNumber for  my numbers, as I know I have 81 (9*9) of them).

Thanks for your answer

Comment: It looks to me that you want an array of two dimensional arrays. Is this correct? If that's the case, you technically will have a 3 dimensional array. My suggestion would be to forget about the int matrix, and just use NSMutableArrays for everything, including your matrix. It'll be a little more writing ( would have to write [[matrix objectAt:i] objectAt: j] instead of matrix[i][j] )  but everything would at least work out in the end, would be less complicated, and may have to write less loops and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSNumber. Checked that out? Otherwise you could go for an C Array.

Comment: I use NSValue to store an array of int, in a NSNumber I only can store single integers, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to put a 2D array of int into an object, why not do just that? Create a class containing one property of type int[9][9], create an object of that class and put your array in it.

Comment: I tried to, but I got problems with array manipulation, especially the setting and getting methods. I don't know how to pass a 2D array as argument...with a pointer ? how to point towards a 2D array ?

Answer (score 0):

```
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b36ce0'
```

I think that TGrid is getting autoreleased. Try this:

```
TGrid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

Then release it in your -dealloc method of course.